# Copy Values with condition in Appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 6 different spreadsheets in one folder they all have one common sheet called "3.reporting"
I would like to only copy values from each spreadsheet where the column year is equal to 2021. Here is the screenshot of the position of the year[screenshot of source spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aawPJ.png)
Below is the code I use to pull the data but it pulls everything including blank rows the the spreadsheet  called "1.master_courses"
Here is a sample [folder](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1wfd-fYucd2aY6cq-Z71NOeZZfFBlabIg) and [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15NBeXP-3V40VOiwXmNFns-rEpwOWhcyIYsRWVdsBnuQ/edit#gid=0) is the destination file spreadsheet

```
function courseMaster() {
  //1NNBpm9zfzvpMbIPlZHvGKUV3BgO
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1NNBpm9zfzvpMbIPlZHvGKUV3BgO");
  var filesIterator = folder.getFiles();
  var file;
  var fileType;
  var ssID;
  var combinedData = [];
  var data;
  while (filesIterator.hasNext()){
    file = filesIterator.next();
    fileType = file.getMimeType();
     if(fileType === "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"){
      ssID = file.getId();
      data = getDataFromSpreadsheet (ssID);
      data = data.map(function(r){ return r.concat([file.getName()]);});
      combinedData = combinedData.concat(data);   
    }//if ends here 
  }//while ends here  
 var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("1.master_courses");
 ws.getRange("A2:AA").clearContent();
 ws.getRange(2, 1, combinedData.length, combinedData[0].length).setValues(combinedData); 
  }
function getDataFromSpreadsheet (ssID){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("3.reporting");
  var data = ws.getRange("A2:Z" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();
  return data
}
///***Sheet_Names***///
function sheetnames() {
  var out = new Array()
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) out.push( [ sheets[i].getName() ] )
  return out 
}
```

Comment: Please provide a sample sheet to replicate your problem.

Comment: @JasonE. I have updated with the sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the line `} // while ends here` paste the line:

```
combinedData = combinedData.filter(x => x[0] == "2021");
```

If you need to add conditions you can do it this way:

```
combinedData = combinedData.filter(x => (x[0] == "2021") && (x[1] != ""));
```

`x[0]` is a first cell (A), `x[1]` is a second cell (B), etc. You can add any conditions for the cells: && (and), || (or), etc. If the result of these conditions is True the row will be left in table (passed the filter), if result is False the row will be omitted (didn't pass the filter).

Comment: is it possible to add another condition to the same filter... Like where col A=2021 and col B is not blank

Comment: It's possible. I've made the addition to my answer.